# Programmatically (VBA) close a window opened with RunCommand

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Ok, first up is my question:
Of course you can open the Access "Unhide Columns" menu with:

```
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUnhideColumns
```

But is there code that could close that pop up menu?  Maybe on a timer, like how you can create a message box to auto close after a set time?

I know this sounds insane, so here's the background to explain why I'm heading down the wrong path.

On a split form I've created a button to load user profiles that show, hide, and rearrange the columns depending on the user's role.
That works fine, but as I learned here on StackExchange: "Design changes made while the form is open in Normal mode can't be saved", so the changes need to be done every time the user opens the form.

I've discovered that just opening and closing the "Unhide Columns" menu triggers access to ask the user if they want to save the layout when the form is closed.  Right now I just set the layout and then open the menu, forcing the user to close it manually, but it would be much smoother if they did not have to do that.  This is just the closest I've come to a workaround that fits our situation.  I know I could set the profile to run whenever the form is open, but some users further customize their layouts beyond the profile and that would interfere with them.  All of the other solutions I can think of are a lot heavier than this would be, assuming I can get it to work.  I'm open to other suggestions though.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are users closing form with the X close? I disable that in design and make them always close forms with a custom button. Code:

`DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo`

I also disable the app Exit and X Close. They close the db with button on main menu form that never closes. Also customize ribbon, hide navigation pane, and disable function keys and right click. And don't teach them about shift key bypass.

Comment: The "X" is still available to them, but users mostly use a button that has code similar to yours.  To test, I changed it to your code.  As is, it made it worse.  It killed the ability of the unhidecolumns command to trigger a save request but didn't save.  
Changing you code to acSaveYes instead did make a change, but not the change I want.  It still won't trigger a column layout save on its own but in conjunction with the unhidecolumns command it saves the layout without asking.  So a mild improvement, but I still need to open the unhidecolumns window and have the user close it.  Thanks